# Are there any APIs or libraries in .NET for image segmentation of characters for OCR?

Tags: .net, ocr, projection, image-segmentation

I am currently doing a project related to OCR for Tamil characters. 
I am now at the segmentation stage. 
I am looking for an API or library for projection profiles for 
segmentation, that i can use with .NET framework since I am using C# 
for development. 
Any other technique for segmentation is also fine, I just want to 
make use of some existing API or library for this stage. 
Your help and suggestions would be very helpful, as I am completely confused
at the moment.

Thankyou

Comment: First you ask: "I am looking for an API or library".  Then you say: "I just don't want to make use of some existing API or library".  Please clarify your question.

Comment: sorry about that, what i meant was "I want to make use of some existing api or library". Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for freeware or commercial solutions ?

OCR is mostly available for printed text, handwritten character recognition is still unreliable.

For printed text, the results are strongly dépendent on image quality (contrast, noise, illumination uniformity...).

As the Tamil characters are rather complex, it is far better if the characters are clearly separated from each other. Touching characters will give you nightmares.

If you share a few sample images, I can advise about feasibility of segmentation.